# expected expression before 'return' and '}' (curly brackets). I have tried changing everything, doesn't run

Tags: expected-exception

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    char a[5];
    for(char i = 0, i < 5, ++i){
        scanf("%c", &a[i]);
    }
    printf("%c", a[5]);
return 0;
}
```

I changed a[5] into a[i] in the printf, nothing changed.
I have compared with this one i found on the net(which works ofc):

```
int main() {
  int values[5];
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
     scanf("%d", &values[i]);
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
     printf("%d\n", values[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `,` instead of semi colon `;` in the for loop.

`for(char i = 0, i < 5, ++i)`

**Correct Usage:**

`for(char i = 0; i < 5; ++i)`

Comment: Wow, i haven't even noticed that! :o do i feel dumb now.
Thank you very much! i wanna read one side of an equation so i need to be able to read both letters and numbers, so afaik i cannot use int.

Edit: int inside the for loop, i gotchu.

Comment: Sure, I'll edit the answer. Please upvote and mark it as answer, it it has helped you. Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Comment: i dont have enough rep but i will try! ^^

Comment: Reps aren't required for upvoting, asking questions or marking answers.